# Ionic HTTP Post successfully sends data but runs error function in app

Tags: python, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to send an HTTP post request using AngularJS and Ionic.
The data is successfully received by my Python-based server, however the error function, rather than success, is called on the simulated device.

Here is my device code:

```
$http(config)
                   .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                      alert("Registered with MC server. Congrats!");
                    })
                    .error(function(err, data, status, headers, config) {
                      alert("Unable to reach MC server to register: try again another time.");
                      alert("Error Info : " + err + data);
                    });
```

Here is my server code:

```
def do_POST(self):
        # Confirm receipt
        # print headers
        print self.headers
        # Extract and print the contents of the POST
        length = int(self.headers['Content-Length'])
        post_data = self.rfile.read(length).decode('utf-8')
        print post_data
        data = json.loads(post_data)
        registerUser(data['email'],data['first'],data['last'],data['uid'],data['devid'])
        #SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler.do_POST(self)
        # response to iphone app
        self.send_response(200) #create header
        response = "Authentication successful." #create response
        self.send_header("Content-Length", str(len(response)))
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write(response) #send response
```

Anyone have any ideas why this is happening?

Thank you!

Comment: That's because some error has occurred in your Python code. Inspect element and you will see that in Network tab. By the way what framework are you using for the "Python-based server"?